# R: Web scraping multiple variables from a table

Tags: r, scrape

I'm attempting to web scrape a web page (https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1986&lang=&page=1) in R using the following code:

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

aviationurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1986"
webpage = read_html(aviationurl)

# define variables of interest
variables = c("Date","Type","Registration","Operator","Fat","Location","Flag","Picture","Category")

# create sequence of numbers (as CSS for each variable contains a number)
colnums = seq(1,length(variables))

#  write commands for pulling each variable into an R dataframe and executing them
eval(parse(paste(variables," = as.data.frame(html_text(html_nodes(webpage,'td:nth-child(",colnums,")')))",sep="")))

# create final table with all variables
df = cbind(parse(variables))
```

However, after the eval command, I get the following error message:

*Error in file(filename, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

If I use the paste command without eval(parse()), and manually C+P the resulting strings, they work fine. So why won't R evaluate them properly?

Open to alternative suggestions, though would like to know why eval isn't working and if there's anything I can do to make this work.

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: please see if my answer helps your question

Answer (score 2):

I think this solves your problem.

```
library(rvest)

aviationurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php? 
Year=1986"
webpage = read_html(aviationurl)

 table <- as.data.frame(html_table(html_nodes(webpage, "table"))) 

head(table)
         date                    type registration
1 03-JAN-1986           Antonov An-2T   CCCP-06101
2 13-JAN-1986        BN-2A-6 Islander       C-GTPB
3 15-JAN-1986      Dassault Falcon 10       F-GBTC
4 15-JAN-1986 Boeing 737-2A8 Advanced       VT-EGD
5 16-JAN-1986           Antonov An-2R       SP-WON
6 18-JAN-1986   SE-210 Caravelle VI-N       HC-BAE
                             operator fat.             location
1 Tselinny gorno-khimicheski kombinat    0        near Shantobe
2                Borealis Exploration    0      Caribou Horn...
3                              Air BG    2 near Vatry/Châlon...
4                     Indian Airlines    0      Tiruchirappa...
5                                 ZUA   NA              Un-Sara
6    SAETA, op.for Aerovias Guatemala   94 near Flores-Santa...
  Var.7 pic cat
1    NA  NA  A1
2    NA  NA  A2
3    NA  NA  A1
4    NA  NA  A2
5    NA  NA  A1
6    NA  NA  A1
```

other method

```
library(rvest)

 aviationurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php? 
Year=1986"
 webpage = read_html(aviationurl)

 # define variables of interest
 variables =c("Date","Type","Registration","Operator","Fat","Location","Flag","Picture","Category")

# create sequence of numbers (as CSS for each variable contains a number)
colnums = seq(1,length(variables))

library(dplyr)
table <- list()
for(i in 1:length(colnums)){
  table[[i]] <- as.data.frame(html_text(html_nodes(webpage, paste0("td:nth-child(",colnums[i],")"))))
}
table <- bind_cols(table)
names(table) <- variables


head(table)
         Date                    Type Registration
1 03-JAN-1986           Antonov An-2T   CCCP-06101
2 13-JAN-1986        BN-2A-6 Islander       C-GTPB
3 15-JAN-1986      Dassault Falcon 10       F-GBTC
4 15-JAN-1986 Boeing 737-2A8 Advanced       VT-EGD
5 16-JAN-1986           Antonov An-2R       SP-WON
6 18-JAN-1986   SE-210 Caravelle VI-N       HC-BAE
                             Operator Fat             Location Flag
1 Tselinny gorno-khimicheski kombinat   0        near Shantobe     
2                Borealis Exploration   0      Caribou Horn...     
3                              Air BG   2 near Vatry/Châlon...     
4                     Indian Airlines   0      Tiruchirappa...     
5                                 ZUA                  Un-Sara     
6    SAETA, op.for Aerovias Guatemala  94 near Flores-Santa...     
  Picture Category
1               A1
2               A2
3               A1
4               A2
5               A1
6               A1
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Chose to use the first method but definitely helpful to know about the alternative way as it will likely come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: code to scrape the three pages with data on the website and bind it together in one data frame.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1986&.  lang=&page="
urls <- paste0(url, 1:3)

scr <- function(url) {
  read_html(url) %>%
   html_nodes("table") %>%
   html_table() %>%
   as.data.frame()
}
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(urls, scr))
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! This was indeed my next step. Was eventually able to use this code as a base to combine data from all years.